# How to search for yanked text in a macro?

Tags: search, cut-copy-paste, macro, ideavim

How do I search for yanked text in a macro properly?

---

I tried the following:

1. `qq`  (start a macro)
2. `yi"` (yank text inbetween ", let's say the yanked text is foo)
3. `/`
4. press `ctrl` + `r`
5. `"`  (I observe that `"` is now replaced by the yanked content: "foo")
6. press `enter`

If I repeat this macro at a new place that yanks some text that is different from the one yanked in the macro when the macro was created, it is not going to search for the newly yanked text. Instead, it always just searches for the text that was yanked when the macro was first created, that is, "foo".

---

My question rephrased:

I want to refer to whatever is in the unnamed register inside the search function. How do I do that?

So,

When I press `/`, what should I know type to refer to the content inside the unnamed register?

I could do:

1. press `ctrl` + `r`
2. type `"` (" because I want to refer to the unnamed register)

But this is not exactly what I want, because now the `"` inside the searching is replaced by the content inside the unnamed register. I simply want to refer to it.

---

Comment: I don't have the described behavior. Could you give the result of the `:reg q` command? I have `yi"/^R*^M` where `^R` and `^M` stand for Ctrl-r and Enter respectively.

Comment: I'm confused by the rephrasing. Could you give us a concrete example of what you try to achieve. I believe it will help us to understand.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt it's entirely possible the "bug" is explained by [tag:ideavim] :(

Comment: @BenKnoble, Now I understand. I didn't paid attention to the IdeaVim tag :-|